# Simple Vim Regular Expression

Tags: regex, vim

I am trying to match

```
^
 ^
```

But not

```
^^
 ^
```

That is, 0 or 1 space followed by exactly one caret. I can't find a way to translate that regex in vim... I currently have `/ \=\^$` but it matches `^^^` (the last caret).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/^\s\=\^\^\@!
```

This is rather confusing because of all the `^` symbols. What you are missing is a negative look-ahead, `\@!`.

For more information see:

```
:h /\@!
```

Comment: You do not need to use parenthesis for look-ahead or look-behind. `\^\@!` and `\%(\^\)\@!` have just the same meaning (not `\^\@!` and `\(\^\)\@!`: here you use capturing parenthesis I assume you don’t need).

Comment: @zyX, I have updated the regex accordingly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
^\s\?\^$
```

It seems to work to me.